# Pagination if statement

Tags: php, html, pagination

I'm sitting at record id 1 and hit the Previous link, it goes to record 0, then record -1, then -2, and so on. I'm trying to show just the 'Next' link if I'm on record id 1, else show both links.

```
<ul class="pager">
    <?php if (href="?read=<?=htmlspecialchars($_GET['read'] = 1)) { ?>
        <li class="previous"><a href="?read=<?=htmlspecialchars($_GET['read'] + 1)?>">Next</a></li>
    <?php } else { ?>
        <li class="previous"><a href="?read=<?=htmlspecialchars($_GET['read'] - 1)?>">Previous</a></li>
        <li class="previous"><a href="?read=<?=htmlspecialchars($_GET['read'] + 1)?>">Next</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: A) `<?php if (href="?read=<?=htmlspecialchars($_GET['read'] = 1)) { ?>` is missing a quote (") somewhere B) is href a variable? or what is the comparison in that statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
    //get page number or set to 1 if not page is set
    $read = isset($_GET['read']) ? (int)$_GET['read'] : 1;
    $limit = 5;
?>
<ul class="pager">
    <?php if ($read > 1): ?>
        <li class="previous"><a href="?read=<?= ($read - 1)?>">Previous</a></li>
    <?php endif ?>
    <?php if ($read < $limit): ?>
        <li class="previous"><a href="?read=<?= ($read + 1)?>">Next</a></li>
    <?php endif ?>
</ul>
```

ps: for NEXT link there should probably class `next` not `previous` but you have `previous` in your code so I left it at it is

Comment: I'm using Bootstrap. The 'previous' class aligns the button to the left, while the 'next' class aligns the button to the right. Kind of confusing.

Comment: So if it is perfect, so mark this answer as resolving problem that everyone could see that it is done now.

Comment: Need to set an upper limit. Lets say there are 5 records. When on record 5 and you hit 'Next', record 6 is blank and does exist.

Comment: 5 records was just an example. Each table has a different number of records. For example, one table has 5 records while another has over 70k. So I'm guessing we need a query that gives the total number of records for that table, and set that value to $limit.

Comment: So you have to count records for  each table.

Comment: Trying this but getting an error: Catchable fatal error: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to string.

$query2 = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM webvulns";
$result2 = mysqli_query($connection, $query2);
confirm_query($result2);

// Get the page number or set it to 1 if no page is set.
$read = isset($_GET['read']) ? (int)$_GET['read'] : 1;
$limit = $result2;

Comment: To get data from query you need to fetch it: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
<?php if (href="?read=<?=htmlspecialchars($_GET['read'] = 1)) { ?>
```

To this

```
<?php if (href="?read=<?=htmlspecialchars($_GET['read'] == 1)) { ?>
```

$_GET['read'] = 1 statement always sets $_GET['read'] variable to 1.

Comment: This line is totally wrong.  @Lee I gave you correct in my answer.